# finding the sum of an alternative series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given $1,-6,11,-16,21,-26,...$ such that it's absolute terms are an arithmetic series.

Need to find the sum of the first $2n$ terms $(S_{2n})$.

So i can see that $1,6,11,16,21,26,...$ is an arithmetic series with $d=5$ and also i can see that $(1-6),(11-16),(21-26),...=-5,-5,-5,...$.

But i can't see how to combine all this into one $S_{2n}$.

Any help?

P.S - appreciate for a simple and clear solution so i could understand because i'm a beginner.

Thank you.

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. It's good that you wrote down how far you got on this problem - it will make it much more likely that you will get useful responses. As to your question, ask yourself how many times -5 appears if the original alternating sum has $2n$ terms. Then add these up as this is still a sum.

Comment: thank you Hans. now i can understand but then i wonder what if i was ask to find the sum of first $n$ terms? is it the same technique?

Comment: For $n$ terms, it depends on whether $n$ is even or odd. If $n=2k$ is even, then you'ĺl get $S_n = -5k$ as the sum. If $n$ is odd, say $n = 2k+1$, then the answer is $-5k$ plus the term number $n = 2k+1$ of the alternating sequence. That terms is always positive, and its value is $1 + 2k \cdot 5 = 1 + 10k$. So then $S_n = -5k + 1 + 10k = 1 + 5k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the first $2n$ terms into two groups:

1st: $1,11,21,...$

2nd: $-6,-16,-26,...$

The first is an arithmetic sequence with common difference $10$, and the second is also an arithmetic sequence but with common difference $-10$.

The sum of the first $n$ terms of the first sequence is:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(1 + 10i) = n + 10\frac{n(n-1)}{2} = n + 5n(n-1) = 5n^2 - 4n$$

The sum of the first $n$ terms of the second sequence:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(-6 -10i) = -6n -10\frac{n(n-1)}{2} = -6n -5n(n-1) = -5n^2 - n$$

Therefore, the sum of the first $2n$ terms of the sequence is:

$$S_n = 5n^2 - 4n - 5n^2 - n = -5n$$

Comment: thank you Ahmed! it's very simple after i saw your solution.